# Half of json disappearing

Tags: python, json, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site in python for prices and for that I am querying a url api endpoint(??). When I copy paste the url with parameters, I get complete JSON in browsers  as well as complete in Chrome Developers Console. My code looks like this..

```
import requests
import json
api_woolies=('https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/Search/products?IsMultisearch=true&IsSpecial=false&PageNumber=1&PageSize=5&SearchTerm=chicken&SortType=Relevance') #the url
woolies_data=(requests.get(api_woolies))
print woolies_data.text   # woolies_data.text actually contains full json what i want
woolies_data_=json.loads(woolies_data.text)  # removes the part I want and leaves with jsondata i dont need
print woolies_data_
```

The response content-type is json. Calling json on reponse object like `woolies_data.json()`, using `json.loads(woolies_data.text)` or `json.loads(woolies_data.content)` removes all the data at the front and starts from `corrections:none` as you can see it in the browser. I tried using `json.dumps` but that adds a backslash and an inverted comma at the start of all the key and values. I researched about this error and I came to know that this happens if data is already jsonified. I just want the relevant data to convert into python object so that I can do some logical parsing like calling products.name/price which I am not able to do in present format of the text since I want to bring the query parameters from client side. It's a real dilemma as I can see the data but not do anything useful. I also don't believe string manipulation would be suitable for the process. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Please learn something about Markdown (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), don't intersperse your code with HTML chunks, there's no need for that.

Comment: Can you share woolies_data.txt? Maybe something in the JSON formatting is wrong...

Comment: I will surely do that.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to get the API response into a Python dict, the following is all you need to do:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/Search/products?IsMultisearch=true&IsSpecial=false&PageNumber=1&PageSize=5&SearchTerm=chicken&SortType=Relevance"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

The [`r.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) function automatically decodes a response's JSON content into a Python dict datastructure, so all you have to do is assign it to a variable, then use regular dictionary operations to access the information you're looking for.

You are being rather over-zealous in your use of parentheses. For example, in

```
woolies_data=(requests.get(api_woolies))
```

the parens surrounding `requests.get(api_woolies)` are not necessary. The same is true when you assign the `api_wollies` variable. If you were to accidentally add a comma `,` inside the parens, you'd create a tuple, which could cause undesired behavior down the line. Finally, I'd suggest using spaces around your assignments:

```
var = "value"
# instead of
var="value"
```

It improves readability, and is recommended according to the Python Style Guide ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: @bobince you're right, I forgot about that. I'll change the wording a bit.